# Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 - installer crashed

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, live-usb, windows-10

Firstly, I apologize if this is a dumb question, I am attempting to install Ubuntu alongside Windows on my Lenovo ideapad 320 for the sole purpose of learning how to use Linux, so this may be a simple question and I am just Linux retarded.  At any rate, this is what I have done and what happened.

I created a bootable USB drive (32GB drive) using Rufus and with the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS version, and it seems to work properly.  I pressed the "Novo" button and accessed the Boot Menu, and selected "Try Ubuntu".  This worked relatively well, although after booting it did not recognize my mouse due to Bluetooth being turned off, so I had to keyboard through the settings to pair my mouse before I could really do anything.

I decided to install Ubuntu and clicked the "Install Ubuntu" shortcut that was already on the desktop.  This opened the installer, and I began selecting the options that made sense.  I clicked install alongside, and install third party software options, at which point it asked me how much space to give Ubuntu.  I arbitrarily decided to give it 300GB of my 1TB hard drive.  After this, it asked me where I was using a time zone map, and after selecting my location the installer seemed to crash.

I could still hear the fans running but the system time wasn't ticking and it did not respond to any keyboard inputs.  After thirty minutes of no changes, I pressed and held the power button to shut it down (which was probably a really bad idea).  I started again by pressing the Novo button, and selected Install Ubuntu.  This loaded the installer again, but as I couldnt access my mouse I could not adjust the slider to choose my hard drive allotment, and also (the most troubling part) it seems as though it was trying to repartition my hard drive.  IE the default showed 300GB for Ubuntu (what I had selected earlier), but only ~300GB for Windows instead of 600 as it was the first time.  I then selected shut down, which it did just fine, and restarted using the Try Ubuntu option from my USB drive again.

This loaded up the live session, obviously because I chose the USB drive, but Ubuntu from harddrive was not an option, presumably because the installer never got that far.  It seems the installer got to the point of partitioning my hard drive and reserving 300GB of space, but no farther.  I dont even see a way to get into the partition, or that either Windows or Ubuntu recognizes it exists.  It seems to think I now have a 600-700GB harddrive instead of a 1TB with a 300GB partition.  I am concerned because I dont want to continue and box windows into ever smaller partitions while I try and fix this.

I perused this forum but I am not sure if any of the solutions I saw are applicable.  I seem to have all of the options to boot Ubuntu via my Boot Menu, and the installer does seem to work at least initially.  I saw many solutions involving codes (most of them involving 'grub', and others involving 'sudo', but as I am trying to install so I can learn those codes, I dont know any of them yet and am reluctant to try them until I am absolutely sure of what they will do.

For now, any help to install Ubuntu using the first partition that was possibly partially created the first time would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance, and I apologize in advance for what my ignorance has gotten me in to...

Comment: Lesson 1: Use a wired mouse instead of relying upon Bluetooth during the install.

Comment: Does Windows still work?

Comment: Lol, the mouse I have has the option of being wired, but Ubuntu still doesnt recognize it, not sure if that is a Linux problem or a mouse problem or just a me problem.  Also, trackpad doesnt work, I dont have a cursor until I pair it using bluetooth, and bluetooth was just the first option I found to get it to work, didnt try others to make it work without bluetooth.  Although I am concerned that because it forgets everything when I boot Ubuntu that unless it works right out of the gate I wont be able to access any settings to make it work during install.

Comment: Also, Windows works, I am using it now to figure access this site and try and figure out what I need to do ahead of time, knowing I will be in online blackout mode once I get enough info to try again lol...

Comment: Does your system NEED to be dual-booted? With your hardware troubles, have you considered an Ubuntu guest VM on the Windows host?

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure.  I am using Windows to run MS Access, so I cant get rid of Windows entirely, but that only eliminates the "make this a dedicated Linux machine" option.  My research ahead of time suggested dual-booting was the best way to try it out and learn, although I dont know enough to know whether or not that is true.  I did see some of the VM options, but again, I dont know enough yet to be able to do that, so I assumed dual-booting would be the easiest for me to do and get started learning about it.  Possibly poor assumption in hind sight lol

Comment: I also fear I may have passed the point of no return by at least starting the partition process.  If I did decide to abandon the dualboot method, I would like to be able to unpartition to get that 300GB back, if that is even a thing I should be worried about.

Comment: Interestingly, Windows still recognizes the full 1TB of harddrive space, only Ubuntu seems to want to ignore it and only use the ~600GB remaining after the first partition attempt.  Not sure if that helps narrow anything down or not...

Comment: Suggestion: Undo the partitioning (Windows can do that). Use the LiveUSB to simply Try Ubuntu. If you want more, install A VM on Windows, and install Ubuntu onto that VM. Once you have greater skills, you can revisit partitioning and dual-booting.

Comment: Agreed, I definitely need to be more knowledgeable before I do something I cant fix lol.  As far as partitioning goes, if Windows shows 1TB of total space, does that mean that Windows doesnt recognize the partition?  It is only Ubuntu that seems to recognize it, in that it only shows the ~600GB as the total available space when the installer gets to that point...

Comment: Does Windows disk and partition tools (real tools, not file manager) show the full 1TB? If so, then perhaps you didn't partition using Windows tools first, before booting the Ubuntu installer. Sounds like you got lucky - failing to partition using Window tools first is an easy way to destroy your Windows install (including all your data).

Comment: You would be correct, I definitely did not partition first, did not know I was supposed to do that...  I feel like an idiot, Id like to think I am reasonable intelligent but there is just so much to know and so much that I dont even know I dont know lol...  Thank you for all your help and suggestions, I ordered several books on Ubuntu/Linux to learn more before I try anything else, hopefully I can tackle it from a less retarded position next time around...

Comment: You're NOT an idiot. Dual-booting used to be easy - before EFI, Fast Boot, Secure Boot, and Win 10 made it super-hard.  But all those 5-year-old oh-it's-so-easy-to-dual-boot blog posts are still at the top of the Google rankings, leading new several new users each day astray. Stick around for a few days, and you will see....

Comment: If you want to try troubleshooting it, you could boot the live session, take a screen shot of the partition setup using `gparted`, and edit that into your question.  Otherwise there is not much to go on here.

Comment: So, update to this question:  I have decided to do a significant amount of research before I do anything that could be irreversible, and with my current level of knowledge, that includes partitioning or attempting to install ubuntu.  Windows has recognized there is something going on, and although I have no idea what it is doing, it has been working its butt off trying (I presume) to fix whatever I may have screwed up in not knowing to partition via windows before attempting to install linux.  Thank you all for you help and guidance, when I do take that leap I will be glad you are all here!

Comment: Also, user535733, if you can post your comment on Nov 16 at 21:44 as an answer, I would be happy to upvote it!  You may not have directly answered the question I asked (which I am quickly learning shouldnt have really been asked at all lol) but you did point me in the right direction as to what went wrong and how I can avoid it next time I try installing!  Thank you again for your help!